# jquerymobile widgets missing from palette in eclipse while working on IBM worklight project

Tags: eclipse, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

i am new to IBM worklight and mobile app developement as it is so i will be very grateful if somebody helps.
configuration
windows 8 64bit
eclipse juno 1.5.2
ibm worklight studio 6.0.0
jquery.mobile-1.3.0
[image: installed plugins]
i have read many forums and questions on stackoverflow itself. they suggest that it will work on jquery.mobile -1.3.1 nut i can't find the specific version online.
Also when i goto help->check for updates it outputs no updates found along with error message:
No repository found at file:/D:/software/ibm%20tools/ibm%20tools/jquery.mobile-1.3.0/.
No repository found at file:/D:/software/ibm%20tools/ibm%20tools/adapt/.
[image: error message screenshot]
so the problem is that when i open the html file of my project only Html tags and html form tag gets opened but a jquerymobile widgets are missing.
[image: jquery widgets missing in palette(red region)] 
what exactly is the problem is it with the way of my jquerymobile import or versions or is it entirely something else if problem is version kindly state me a few resources if you can!!
i am really in need to get my project done if anyone helps again i will be really grateful.

Comment: jQuery Mobile 1.3.1: http://jquerymobile.com/resources/download/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery Mobile 1.3.1: http://jquerymobile.com/resources/download/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.zip

With this version of jQuery Mobile you will be able to see the Palette view in Eclipse while using Worklight Studio's RPE.